# tables in dynamoDB that are queriable

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have been trying to implement a post/replies scenario like google+ in dynamoDB as a private project. This is the first time i am trying to implement a nosql table and am trying to wrap my head around the concept. I  understand that related table columns can be embedded into the original table as follows...

```
Post { userid:1, 
       postdata: "hello",Comment[
                                  {userid: 2, postdata: "howdy", date: some-date},
                                  {userid: 3, postdata: "higuys", date: some-other-date}
                                ], 
       date: today}
```

Now, if this were the way to code the annotated table, it is easy to retrieve by userid and date all the posts and comments for one conversation. But if we need to find a specific comment and update it, is it possible or do we have to 'scan' a table? I have read about scan resulting in results breaking throughput constraints in large data and don't want to use it. Query seem to be limited in operators for comparison and retrieval. So, am i on right path in creating the table this way? I may have to embed other data into table like Audio, video documents and pictures per 'conversation'. Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DynamoDB, your entire entity can't be larger than 64kB, so you don't want to embed your comments directly in the post unless you know they will be very small.

It would probably work better to have a list of comment-ids in the post, along with whatever metadata you need to know which ones to retrieve.  DynamoDB's low latency means you can have several cycles of request->retrieve->request for every pageload, as long as the number is fixed.

Large embedded content (even larger texts, like blog posts) aren't suitable for DynamoDB, you probably want something like S3 or CloudFront for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the limitations. I'm planning on using the DynamoDB only for storing the userids with their metadata. I plan on storing the files in S3 only. Does the request->retrieve->request cycle take a hit on throughput as throughput is defined in number of units/sec than say millisec? It is going to be tough to estimate the throughput requirements. Will the queries do not get executed at all if they exceed throughput requirements or will they be throttled?

Comment: You'll get a `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` error back if you exceed your throughput.  In a production-level system you'll need to have backoff+retry or error handling in place in case this happens.